# How to read a line while reading a file in Python

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

Imagine that another filename in the same directory is inside the txt file we're currently in:
For example, let file A be the following:

```
B.txt
       computer
    science
```

How would it be possible to read the other lines and go into B.txt after we're done reading?

Comment: [1:] works pretty well, it won't hinder your code. You can get the file name by  listofwords[0] and then iterate over all others using list comprehension.

Comment: I managed to do the second part so i edited it out of the question (my question was a merge of 2 questions anyway so this is for the better good) thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read first line separately, you can do it with `readline()`. Loop then proceeds to read the file from the second line to the end of file:

```
import os


def read_files_to_list(wordlist, file):
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        newfile = f.readline()
        newfile = newfile.strip()   # removes \n and whitespaces

        if not os.path.exists(newfile):
            wordlist.append(newfile)
            newfile = None

        for line in f:
            line_clean = line.strip()
            wordlist.append(line_clean)

    return wordlist, newfile


next_file = "A.txt"
listofwords = []
while next_file is not None:
    listofwords, next_file = read_files_to_list(listofwords, next_file)
```

Comment: File B was an example, i want to repeat this process for multiple files like this (each containing the name of the other file to be opened in its first line)

Comment: @QueensGambyte Please edit the question to clarify that, or ask a new one. Note that it would be easier for everyone trying to help you if you made your questions clear, separate and specific - you've asked two, got one solved, edited it out, now you're altering the criteria for the remaining one. If questions are tightly related, it's good to provide them as context - otherwise, no harm in asking more than one.